# Can't convert std::array to int?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, stl

I am just learning c++ and am attempting to understand arrays.. So forgive my ignorance on what's wrong here.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

void readArray(int *readfile, int ArraySize){
    int Interator;
    for(Interator = 1; Interator < ArraySize; Interator++){
        cout << " " << readfile[Interator];
    }
}

int main(){
    std::array<int, 5> array2={{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}};
    readArray(array2, array2.end());
}
```

> Error: Can't Convert 'std::array' to 'int*' for arg '1'to void 'readArray'

How would I fix this?

Comment: There a lot errors, for example **readArray** uses a pointer as 1st param and you are passing by value instead by reference. **end()** points to the last item of the array, not the actual size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot convert `std::array` to `int*` as compiler says. For such conversion you can use plain old array:

```
void readArray(int *readfile, int ArraySize)
{
    int Interator;
    for(Interator = 0; Interator < ArraySize; Interator++)
    {
        cout << " " << readfile[Interator];
    }
}

int main()
{
    //std::array<int, 5> array2={{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}};
    int array2[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    readArray(array2, 5);
}
```

Also, `Interator` is changed to start from zero. If you need `std::array` then use `std::array::begin()` and `std::array::begin()`:

```
void readArray2(const std::array<int, 5>& a)
{
    for (auto elem : a)
        cout << " " << elem;
}

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 5> array2={{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}};
    //int array2[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    readArray2(array2);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just browse [some reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/data) to discover that `std::array` has a `T* data()` and a `constexpr size_type size()` which can and should be used for that purpose.

But this is a poor solution. The best solution would be to use iterators directly, eg:

```
template <typename T> void readArray(const T& data) {
  for (const auto& element : data)
    cout << element;
}

std::array<int, 5> data1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
readArray(data1);
std::vector<int> data2 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
readArray(data2);
std::list<int> data3 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
readArray(data3);
```

Which would expect `T` to be a type that has proper `begin` and `end()` overloads.

It makes no sense to tag questions with *C++11* if you try to use *C* solutions,